# Как из Excel считать информацию в TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, office

Подскажите, как из Excel считать информацию в TextBox.

Comment: Честно говоря понятия не имею что это. Но нагуглил


https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E+%D0%B2+TextBox%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ezKzU8iUKIHK8gfKkoDADQ

Answer (score 5):

Здравствйте, у вас есть как минимум несколько вариантов, например

1. Interop [Opening and Navigating Excel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5123/Opening-and-Navigating-Excel-with-C)
2. OleDb [Reading/Writing Excel using OLEDB](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB)

Я бы порекомендовал вам использовать OleDb подход

Answer (score 2):

Я в паралельном вопросе кидал очень простенькую минималистическую реализацию через Interop . Она хоть и довольно медленная, но вполне рабочая.

[разделять ячейки таблицы запятой, считывая их построчно из файла Excel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/184962/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-excel?rq=1)

вполне возможно что для ваших задач даной реализации будет достаточно.

---

UPD: Написал более быструю либу. Ее ты найдешь здесь:

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Comment: Добавьте ещё пример кода, как с помощью вашей библиотеки выполнить задачу — и ответ будет просто отличный. (Код библиотеки не надо переписывать, именно как подключить и использовать.)

Comment: вообщето там по ссылке пример использования уже есть. Как подключать -- скопировать код и установить NuGet-ы которые оно попросит. Все.