# Чтение данных из документа Microsoft Excel

Tags: c#, excel

Суть программы: надо считать все данные из документа Microsoft Excel:

1. Открываю документ.
2. Открываю лист и циклом считываю каждую ячейку.
3. Записываю в массив (и так каждый столбик).

(мне не требуется создавать двумерный)

Вот я задался вопросом: а можно ли как это все это ускорить? Ведь считывание из каждой отдельной ячейки существенно нагружает компьютер.

Или как можно узнать размерность столбца, то есть количество заполненных ячеек, пока не начнутся пустые? Может есть какие-то свойства подобные `array.Length`?

Comment: Э... Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, notepad, Ctrl+V = TSV?

Comment: @Discord, excel и сам умеет сохраняться в csv

Comment: Возможно может помочь библиотека [EPPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). Значительно облегчит задачу

Comment: Здесь [в ответах](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/184962/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-excel?rq=1) я выкладывал довольно медленный, но вполне рабочий код. Как следствие можно читать и записывать файл и **работать с ячейками как с двухмерным массивом.** update: вот либа работает по той

Comment: @Andrew если вы считаете что вопрос является дубликатом - стоит отметить его тревогой.

Comment: Здесь найдешь ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb И даже готовую либу по взаимодействия с ексель файлами как с 2хмерным масивом. Работает быстро.

Answer (score 2):

Я пользуюсь либой EPPlus.

Можно сделать так:

```
var rowCnt = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
var colCnt = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column + 1;
```

И получить размерность.

Конечно, наверное, можно сделать это и стандартными средствами, но данная библиотека очень удобна лично для меня.